# Excel - Conditional Formatting of Area Codes from Named Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of phone numbers and a named range "NE" of area codes and I want to highlight the phone numbers that begin with the area codes. I can't for the life of me figure out what that formula should look like.

The area codes are in Z2:Z72. The nine or 10 digit phone numbers are in cells C51:C1587.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,NE&"*"))
```

where A1 is the cell you want formatted.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing occurs when I enter this information. I'm trying =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C51,NE&"*")) and no formatting is happening.

Comment: Then I'd guess you're entering the phone numbers as actual numbers. They need to be text for that formula to work. If they're real numbers, use: `=COUNT(1/(SEARCH(NE,C51)=1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional formatting and use a formula as below:

```
=countif($A:$A,left($B1,3))=1
```

In my example, all of the Area Codes are strings of 3 digits and are in the Column "A:A" and your cell is in B1. You can adapt it depending on your Digit Codes

You can also use Rory's answer in a conditional formatting and it should work just fine.

Note: as mentioned in one of the comments, this would only work if the numbers are entered as text in both the Area Codes Range and in the phone number Range

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing occurs when I enter this information. I'm trying =countif($Z2:$Z72,left($C51,4)) and no formatting is happening.

Comment: Can you show an example of your Area Codes and of the phone numbers?

Comment: Area codes: `203`, `860`, `207`. Phone numbers: `2075555555`, `8605555555`, `2035555555`.

Answer (score 0):

Select C51:C1587 then create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula.

```
=countifs(NE, left($C51, 3), NE, "<>")
```